# in a directory with files that have numbers in filenames, how to find greater or smaller than x

Tags: regular-expression, find

OUT-OF-CONTEXT (only a comparison to illustrate the "what i want to do") : when querying a database, when can select where id > 5 and id < 99......

CONTEXT-part1 : in a directory with lots of files.

CONTEXT-part2 : the filenames are like 123.txt 145.txt 233.txt 678.txt (not in sequence)

WHAT I WAN TO DO : find files that have (in the filename) greater then 127 and lower than 300

EXAMPLE : in the "part2" find 145.txt 233.txt

WHAT I BEGAN TO TRY : `find . -regextype sed -regex '.*/[1-9].ref'`

but how to better do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `zsh` shell, the globbing pattern `part2/<128-299>.txt` would match all names in the `part2` directory that start with a number strictly between 127 and 300, and ends with the string `.txt`.

Example:

```
$ tree
.
|-- part1
|   |-- 123.txt
|   |-- 145.txt
|   |-- 233.txt
|   `-- 678.txt
`-- part2
    |-- 123.txt
    |-- 145.txt
    |-- 233.txt
    `-- 678.txt

2 directories, 8 files
```

```
$ printf '%s\n' part2/<128-299>.txt
part2/145.txt
part2/233.txt
```

In a shell like `bash`, the following set of patterns would do the same

```
part2/12[89].txt part2/1[3-9][0-9].txt part2/2[0-9][0-9].txt
```

*provided that the `nullglob` shell option is set*, or you may get unexpanded patterns as a result:

```
$ printf '%s\n' part2/12[89].txt part2/1[3-9][0-9].txt part2/2[0-9][0-9].txt
part2/12[89].txt
part2/145.txt
part2/233.txt
```

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ printf '%s\n' part2/12[89].txt part2/1[3-9][0-9].txt part2/2[0-9][0-9].txt
part2/145.txt
part2/233.txt
```

In a shell without `nullglob` (e.g. `sh`), you will have to use a loop to test for the existence of each generated string:

```bsh
for name in part2/12[89].txt part2/1[3-9][0-9].txt part2/2[0-9][0-9].txt
do
    [ -e "$name" ] && printf '%s\n' "$name"
done
```

With `find`, you would use the same type of pattern as in a non-`zsh` shell:

```bsh
find part2 -name '12[89].txt' -o -name '1[3-9][0-9].txt' -o -name '2[0-9][0-9].txt'
```

but you may obviously use `zsh` too here,

```bsh
find part2 -exec zsh -c '[[ $1:t == <128-299>.txt ]]' zsh {} \; -print
```

This calls an in-line `zsh` script for each found pathname and compare its filename using the pattern similar to the on at the start of this answer.

`find` would obviously recurse down into sub-directories beneath `part2` too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. `find /pathtodirectory -exec zsh -c '[[ $1:t == <128-299>.txt ]]' zsh {} \; -print` worked like a charm ;)